# Why does the GetType return null in the following scenario (F#)

Tags: .net, f#

1. I have checked the spelling of the namespaces & modules
2. This module is in FSharp.Core.dll which is automatically loaded in F# applications and REPL

`let t = Type.GetType("Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions")`

(run in REPL)

My ultimate aim is to get a methodInfo of one of the functions / static methods inside this module.

Comment: As the MSDN library tells you, It must be the assembly qualified type name.  Which is "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives+IntrinsicFunctions, FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Having the assembly version number in that string is the basic rub, lots of FSharp.Core versions around.  You'll be much ahead by not spinning that wheel of fortune and use typeof<> instead.

Comment: @HansPassant How would you use typeof<> in this scenario? Surely it would also need the assembly?